# 404 page is displayed in plain text (iis7)

Tags: iis, iis-7, http-status-code-404, mime-types

Heey all,

I have a problem with my custom 404 page.
domain.com/lalala -> displays the 404 page in plain text
domain.com/lalala.html -> displays the page correctly

The problem is not present in Internet Explorer, but only in Firefox/Chrome.

I think this all has something to do with mime types. I tried add a mime type rule:
 .* -> text/html but no result.

By the way, it hosts a sharepoint 2007 site.

Anyone suggestions?
Tnx

Answer (score 2):

I did some poking around for you, and the consensus seems to be that this is caused in Sharepoint by invalid and invisible characters in the default Sharepoint 404 file.  The solution seems to be to recreate a 404 page from scratch (don't copy/paste), overwrite, and try again.

IE is generally more forgiving about the content-type header than FF or Chrome, so I'm not surprised it works there.